# Android SeekBar's state become pressed when not touch it

Tags: android, android-view, android-seekbar

This is may layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:maxHeight="2dip"
        android:minHeight="2dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/drawable_seekbar_thumb" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I set an `OnClickListener` to the `RelativeLayout`. The strange thing is that when I touch the `RelativeLayout`, the `SeekBar` performs like I press it, it's thumb become the drawable when it's state is pressed. I think it's state become pressed.

Is this a bug and how to deal with it?

Comment: I see you've made 3 other questions since I posted this answer. If this helped you please accept the answer so we can both get rep, if not let me know where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewGroups` seem to pass their state down to their children when they are clickable as seen in this question: [View gets its drawable state (pressed, etc...) from its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380685/view-gets-its-drawable-state-pressed-etc-from-its-parent)

This may be happening because you set the `OnClickListener` to the `RelativeLayout`.

My first inclination would be to put a `Button` behind the `SeekBar` as a sibling to the `SeekBar`, and using that for your OnClick action.

You could also override your `RelativeLayout`, and do nothing on `setPressed`

[Android: Child elements sharing pressed state with their parent even when duplicateParentState specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741908/android-child-elements-sharing-pressed-state-with-their-parent-even-when-duplic)

According to the docs: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

> Handling touch events in a ViewGroup takes special care, because it's
>   common for a ViewGroup to have children that are targets for different
>   touch events than the ViewGroup itself. To make sure that each view
>   correctly receives the touch events intended for it, override the
>   onInterceptTouchEvent() method.

So it seems this is intended behavior. If you want to avoid this behavior it looks like you will need to override the `ViewGroup` (`RelativeLayout`) or use a `View` that is not a parent to the `SeekBar` for this event.

Answer (score 15):

Just set

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
```

To your seekbar

Comment: This fixed my problem, Thanks Vadim!!